# How to send myself an email every 30 min as a reminder?

Tags: windows, email, microsoft-outlook, automation, timer

How to send an email to myself every 30 min, until I stop it?

I'm working on a special type of support case and I need to update my clients every 30 min. So, if I received an email every 30 min that contained the template, I would just need to fill in the blanks and forward it on. Easy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Schedule a recurring Windows task (Control Panel -> Schedule Task) to run a command line like:

```
outlook.exe /c ipm.note /m "customer@company.com?cc=boss@support.com&subject=Status%20Report&body=Dear%Customer" /a attachment.txt
```

and set the recurrence to 5 min before you need to answer, then up pops the message window and you can type in the status.

also have a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248569/starting-outlook-and-having-an-email-pre-populated-from-command-line

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look at [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) for this kind of automated job.

Comment: This site is fantastic. Looks like an hour is the smallest unit of time, but that might be okay. And I'll update my Facebook status at the same time!

Comment: Maybe setup two same tasks, each running 30 minutes apart? :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a UNIX geek, so I'd set up Cygwin with a cronjob that would do this.  If there are any UNIX machines where you're at, I'd ask for a cronjob on them to do this.

I know there is a Windows scheduler, you could probably find some utility that can send emails, and schedule that on the Windows side.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Boomerang plugin for chrome if you are using Gmail and chrome. You can nicely schedule the email

Please check this.. 
http://www.boomeranggmail.com/

A good read -

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239087

Answer (score 0):

Rather than sending an email yourself, use OUTLOOK and set a remainder.

Refer **[Create a recurring calendar reminder](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-a-recurring-calendar-reminder-HA001098272.aspx)**

Comment: I was thinking this too, but the OQ wants to use the email.

Comment: Basically sending an email to self, it will become a spam...

Answer (score 0):

[Ping Mail](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-ping_email) (with GUI) that send emails to a specified email address every few seconds (minutes, hours).

[image]